# Why does the cpu store the current instructions into a stack once a system interrupt happens?

Tags: computer-science

I was reading about it and was thinking surely the queue first in first out system would make more sense than using a stack because the last instruction will become the first right because it's lifo?

Answer (score 2):

The CPU does not store the *instructions*, it stores the instruction pointer, along with the state of the registers.

Think of putting a post-it in a book so you can get back to that page.

Answer (score 0):

No. You have interrupts with same or different priorities. Interrupts with same priority will be handled in lifo order - but only one at a time. So that lifo queue would only ever have one entry. But with different priorities, a high priority interrupt can interrupt one with lower priority, so a stack is appropriate here.